# Javascript - Call function by its name & arguments stored in variables, (ideally without `eval`, but ok if only way)

Tags: javascript, function, class, variables, dynamic

Relative newbie to JS and node(though I don't think the fact that it's node matters, but just in case), but learning fast.  Probably more detail in this question than needed to ask it, but I'm attempting to include in here some explanation of what I do and don't already understand, in case that's helpful context.  I suspect there's something simple I'm missing here...

I have a class A with a bunch of (static, though I don't think that matters?) functions in it.  They all do pretty specific things.  I have another class B calling functions in A based on the desired function name and arguments being in variables in B.

I understand I could do something like this:

```
class A {
    static doIt(theFunctionName, theArguments) {
        if (theFunctionName == 'asdf') {
            this.asdf(theArguments);
        } else if (theFunctionName == 'qwer') {
            this.qwer(theArguments);
        } else if (theFunctionName == 'zxcv') {
            this.zxcv(theArguments);
        // } else if ( .. etc ...) {
        //  ... etc ...
        } else {
            //return some kind of error or whatever
        }
    }

    static asdf(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
    static qwer(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
    static zxcv(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
}


class B {
    constructor(...) {
        this.theFunctionName = ...;
        this.theArguments = [...];
    }
    myResult = A.doIt(this.theFunctionName, this.theArguments);
}
```

Further, I understand I can access **properties** of an object dynamically:

```
obj[myKey] = something;
```

or

```
myResult = obj[key]
```

But **functions**?

I believe I'm looking for some way to do the latter with functions not just properties - some way to do the functions stuff more dynamically without all the `if ... else if ...` ?

I understand functions are first class in JS, and can be passed around like objects. But I'm not sure that helps here since I'm not passing the functions themselves, I'm choosing a function to call based on its name and arguments in variables... right?

I've tried a couple of things attempting to use the principles from the properties examples with functions but not getting the desired results.  I'm guessing either this really can't be done (without all the `if... else if...` ... or I'm missing something simple.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first-class members in JavaScript. An object that has a property whose value is a string is not *fundamentally* that different from one with a property whose value is a function. Ordinary bracket notation works just fine with function properties and methods:

```js
class A {
    static doIt(theFunctionName, theArguments) {
        const fn = this[theFunctionName];
        if (fn) {
          return fn(theArguments);
        } else {
            //return some kind of error or whatever
        }
    }

    static asdf(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
    static qwer(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
        return 'quer ran';
    }
    static zxcv(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
}


class B {
    constructor() {
        this.theFunctionName = 'qwer';
        this.theArguments = 'foobar';
        console.log(A.doIt(this.theFunctionName, this.theArguments));
    }   
}
const b = new B();
```

That said, this design pattern looks a bit odd - A does not have any own-properties on instances, so it's somewhat weird for A to be a class; it'd make more sense to be a normal object.

```js
const A = {
    doIt(theFunctionName, theArguments) {
        const fn = this[theFunctionName];
        if (fn) {
          return fn(theArguments);
        } else {
            //return some kind of error or whatever
        }
    },
    asdf(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    },
    qwer(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
        return 'quer ran';
    },
    zxcv(theArguments) {
        //do stuff and return something
    }
}


class B {
    constructor() {
        this.theFunctionName = 'qwer';
        this.theArguments = 'foobar';
        console.log(A.doIt(this.theFunctionName, this.theArguments));
    }   
}
const b = new B();
```

Comment: 1. Thanks. That makes sense & would appear to be the 'simple' thing I was 'missing' :-)   2. Thanks for the tip about class vs object. Admittedly I'm coming from languages with traditional class based OOP and still getting my head around JS's prototype thing. Good tip for elsewhere in my app, though in this case there's more to it that I didn't include. But… I'll reconsider that given your point. That said, isn't 'class' just syntax sugar for certain object syntax anyway? Underneath is there any significant difference between your class code & your const code?

Comment: *isn't 'class' just syntax sugar for certain object syntax anyway?* No, a class is very different. With a class, the methods are being put onto the `ClassName.prototype` object. Classes can be instantiated with `new` (and readers of the code will *expect* a class to be instantiated for some purpose, else there's no point to the class). Classes also have various additional syntax, such as class fields, `constructor`s, `super`, and `static`. But if all you want is to organize functions into a data structure, using a plain object is much simpler and will make more sense to readers of the code.

Comment: @CaptainPerformance Fair enough.  Makes sense.  I appreciate the explanation. Thanks!